# Git post-receive Host Key verification failed

Tags: git, githooks

Have 3 servers: Local, Bare, Development.

The following workflow works perfectly:

```
1. Make my local changes 
2. git push to Bare 
3. ssh into Bare 
4. $ ssh ip.of.Development.server "cd /path/to/Development/repo; git pull"
```

This does exactly what you would expect, content gets pulled to my Development server, displays on the page, all is well.

However, if I move the last line to my hooks/post-receive file on Bare, I get a

```
remote: Host key verification failed.
```

I can ssh from Development to Bare without issue and without using a password (after I set up an RSA pair).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand SSH, it is not commutative -- Development can know about Bare (Development can have Bare's public key) while Bare can be ignorant of Development (Bare does **not** have Development's public key).

I would verify that Bare is set up correctly for SSH to Development.